# Longitude is not updated

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, uwp-xaml

I have a mapControl with buttons Select/Cancel and two TextBlocks for see coordinate. After tapped Select button, are calculating the address is from the got coordinates(LatitudeMap and LongitudeMap).

```
    private async void SelectCoordinate_Tapped(object sender, TappedRoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        LatitudeText = LatitudeMap;
        LongitudeText = LongitudeMap;

        MapLocationFinderResult result = await reverseGeocode(sender, e);
        if (result.Status == MapLocationFinderStatus.Success)
        {
            AddressText = result.Locations[0].Address.Town + "," + result.Locations[0].Address.Street + "," + result.Locations[0].Address.StreetNumber;
        }
        MapVisibility = false;
    }
```

The LatitudeMap and LongitudeMap get after tapped on the map:

```
    private void AddMapIcon_Tapped(MapControl sender, MapInputEventArgs args)
    {
        MapIcon icon;
        icon = new MapIcon();

        if (icon != null)
        {
            MapWithPin.MapElements.Clear();
        }

        var tappedGeoPosition = args.Location.Position;
        Geopoint Point = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() { Latitude = tappedGeoPosition.Latitude, Longitude = tappedGeoPosition.Longitude });
        icon = new MapIcon { Location = Point, NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0), ZIndex = 0 };
        MapWithPin.MapElements.Add(icon);
        MapWithPin.Center = Point;

        LatitudeMap = Convert.ToString(tappedGeoPosition.Latitude);
        LongitudeMap = Convert.ToString(tappedGeoPosition.Longitude);
        Select.IsEnabled = true;
    }
```

Problem is that the LontitudeText is not seen in the LontitudeTextBlock.

[image]

Comment: can you give more information how are you binding the LontitudeText ?

Comment: What is the value of `tappedGeoPosition.Latitude`? `tappedGeoPosition.Longitude`?

Comment: <TextBlock Text="{x:Bind LatitudeText, Mode=OneWay}" />
<TextBlock Text="{x:Bind LongitudeText, Mode=OneWay}"/>

Comment: tappedGeoPosition.Latitude and tappedGeoPosition.Longitude it is coordinates PinIcon on the map.

Comment: Could you edit the question and add the code of LongitudeText and LatitudeText properties? (the getter and setter)

Comment: Please check if the `LongitudeText` property is actually updated after you set it. It doesn't seem there is anything wrong with the code except the property name typo.

Comment: In debug LongitudeText and LatitudeText seeing a correctly. Why I see only LatitudeText?  - I don't understand. This is strang.

Comment: It is extremely strange... Please try doing clean of the solution and deleting the `bin` and `obj` folders, if some temporary file isn't at cause

Comment: Have you implemented [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.inotifypropertychanged) interface in your page class?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    public string LatitudeText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LatitudeTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LatitudeTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LatitudeTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LatitudeText), typeof(string), typeof(AddLocationControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => {}));


    public string LongitudeText
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(LongitudeTextProperty); }
        set { SetValue(LongitudeTextProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty LongitudeTextProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(LongitudeText), typeof(string), typeof(AddLocationControl), new PropertyMetadata(null, (d, e) => {}));
```

Correct property.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the typo in the name of the `LongitudeTexttProperty` dependency property name. It should be `LongitudeTextProperty`.

Comment: This did not decide it problem.